# Will git revert overwrite my cherry pick commit?

Tags: git

After pushing changes to branch A I noticed that I commited those in the wrong branch. So I cherry-picked my commit into branch B and reverted the original commit in branch A.

But what if I merge branch A and B into my development branch, will my revert commit overwrite the cherry-picked one?

Comment: git checkout A
git merge dev
git checkout B
git merge dev

you will have updates from B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git checkout A 
git merge dev
git checkout B
git merge dev
```

you will have updates from B, because nothing has been changed on A